# Redirect to an external URL from controller action in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have noticed the following code is redirecting the User to a URL inside the project,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm loginForm, 
                          BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    String redirectUrl = "yahoo.com";
    return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
}
```

whereas, the following is redirecting properly as intended, but requires http:// or https://

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm loginForm, 
                              BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
    {
        String redirectUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
    }
```

I want the redirect to always redirect to the URL specified, whether it has a valid protocol in it or not and do not want to redirect to a view. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You can do it with two ways.

First:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", projectUrl);
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

Second:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + projectUrl);
}
```

Comment: Its even simpler if you directly return a String rather then the ModelAndView.

Comment: It seems that in the first method you should set return code to 302. Otherwise a server would return a response with code 200 and Location header which does not cause redirect in my case (Firefox 41.0).

Comment: Can we also add cookies during redirect to External URL.

Comment: First method requires `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)`

Comment: @Rinat Mukhamedgaliev     In this ModelAndView("redirect:" + projectUrl);  Statement what would be the key will be taken as default, if the added thing is value ?

Comment: The first way is the best, since it does not require Spring MVC.

Comment: @Rinat Mukhamedgaliev, one question please. In the code above, is it possible to replace the object `projectUrl` with multiple URL's that come from Thymeleaf? Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 88):

You can use the `RedirectView`. Copied from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html):

> View that redirects to an absolute, context relative, or current request relative URL

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/to-be-redirected")
public RedirectView localRedirect() {
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
    return redirectView;
}
```

You can also use a `ResponseEntity`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/to-be-redirected")
public ResponseEntity<Object> redirectToExternalUrl() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI yahoo = new URI("http://www.yahoo.com");
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setLocation(yahoo);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
}
```

And of course, return `redirect:http://www.yahoo.com` as mentioned by others.

Comment: The RedirectView was the only one that seemed to work for me!

Comment: I am having a stange behavour wiwth Redirect View, on webshpere i am getting:
[code][27/04/17 13:45:55:385 CDT] 00001303 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Error de servlet]-[DispatcherPrincipal]: java.io.IOException: pattern not allowed
 at mx.isban.security.components.SecOutputFilter$WrapperRsSecured.sendRedirect(SecOutputFilter.java:234)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:145)[code]

Answer (score 66):

You can do this in pretty concise way using `ResponseEntity` like this:

```
  @GetMapping
  ResponseEntity<Void> redirect() {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
        .location(URI.create("http://www.yahoo.com"))
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: This answer is perfect because it allows redirects and also you can choose to not redirect and just return something in the body. It's very flexibel.

Comment: @k13i I have the same problem in my app, in which I need to pass a list of URL's stored in DB back to the controller for redirection purposes. How can I replace the `URI.create("http://www.yahoo.com")` with values handled from Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 54):

Looking into the actual implementation of [UrlBasedViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html) and [RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) the redirect will always be contextRelative if your redirect target starts with /. So also sending a //yahoo.com/path/to/resource wouldn't help to get a protocol relative redirect.

So to achieve what you are trying you could do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm loginForm, 
                          BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    String redirectUrl = request.getScheme() + "://www.yahoo.com";
    return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
}
```

Comment: But in this way the redirect is a GET or does it remain a POST? How do I redirect as POST?

Comment: Well actually per default this is returning a 302 which means it should issue a GET against the provided url. For redirection keeping the same method you should also set a different code (307 as of HTTP/1.1). But I'm pretty sure that browsers will block this if it is going against an absolute address using a different host/port-combination due to security issues.

Answer (score 37):

Another way to do it is just to use the `sendRedirect` method:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void redirectToTwitter(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://twitter.com");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For me works fine:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> redirectToExternalUrl() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI("http://www.google.com");
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setLocation(uri);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
}
```

Comment: I think this method is better than RedirectView as it is working in the postman also.

Answer (score 9):

For external url  you have to use "http://www.yahoo.com" as the redirect url.

This is explained in the [redirect: prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) of Spring reference documentation.

> redirect:/myapp/some/resource

will redirect relative to the current Servlet context, while a name such as

> redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path

will redirect to an absolute URL

Comment: This is the most accurate answer imo. The op was asking to redirect the URL as an absolute URL even it has no scheme in it. The answer is: no you can't, you have to specify the scheme. All the rest answers I see work because they use `http://www.yahoo.com`, `http://www.google.com`, etc. as an example input of their solution. If they use `www.yahoo.com`, no matter `ResponseEntity` or `redirect:`, it will break. Tried with Spring boot 2.5.2 and Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html#RedirectView%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) where you can provide the contextRelative parameter?

Comment: That parameter is useful for paths that start (or don't) with `/` to check if it should be relative to the webapp context. The redirect request will still be for the same host.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and solved "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check ..." issue.

**Controller**

```
    RedirectView doRedirect(HttpServletRequest request){

        String orgUrl = request.getRequestURL()
        String redirectUrl = orgUrl.replaceAll(".*/test/","http://xxxx.com/test/")

        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView()
        redirectView.setUrl(redirectUrl)
        redirectView.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)
        return redirectView
    }
```

**and enable securty**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In short `"redirect://yahoo.com"` will lend you to `yahoo.com`.

where as `"redirect:yahoo.com"` will lend you `your-context/yahoo.com` ie for ex- `localhost:8080/yahoo.com`

Comment: both solutions have the same command : 
"In short "redirect:yahoo.com" vs "where as "redirect:yahoo.com",
and only the relative url redirection is working.