# unable to direct request from one war to another war using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my project deployed on tomcat there are two Wars. I have to redirect the request from one war to another war on a UI action. 
It is currently based on Spring MVC architecture. So I have added this piece of code in the first war to redirect the requests to my other war, but was unable to redirect it.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/monetize")
public class MyFirstWarController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFirstWarController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showConsumerInterests(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        //WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
        logger.info("In the First War Servlet Context");

        servletContext = servletContext.getContext("/monetize");
        return "monetize/dashboard";
    }

}
```

I am trying to reach Controller of my Second War, where I have provided the MVC controller for the request `http://MyLocalHost:8080/monetize/dashboard`, with a similar Controller like the above.
Is there any thing I need to provide in the ViewResolver. I couldn't find any solution to this on the net.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-view

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to an external URL from controller action in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should add [`redirect:`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) prefix into returned value of your controller.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showConsumerInterests(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    //any logic
    return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/monetize/dashboard";
}
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc).