# How to redirect from spring controller to struts action class in the applcn with spring and struts?

Tags: spring, struts

An application which is developed in struts 1.x version and now it is migrating to spring latest version(4.2.1). I am reusing the exusting struts action classes. To execute some functionality i am writing controller class to set certain value after which i have to call struts action class. 
I know in spring there is an option named "redirect" to redirect to another method by specifying the url as return "redirect:/url". 
My question here is will "redirect" keyword work to redirect to struts action from spring controller class? Your answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A redirect is a redirect, it doesn't matter what you're redirecting to.

Comment: Hi dave newton, here since the application is having two container one for spring and one for struts, spring redirect will not be knowing which url it has to redirect.

Comment: But... you give it the URL to redirect to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17955777/438992

Comment: when you return "redirect:blammy" from a spring controller, the request is redirected to blammy.  The implementation of blammy has exactly zero impact on the redirection.

Comment: Redirect won't work, if users request A but the server returns B, users will think B is A and after they request B they can't get A.

Comment: Redirect means the request the made from client i.e. browser. Browser makes the request.

Comment: @KunalSurana you are right. This is not going to work anyway. Is there anyway where I can redirect from spring controller to struts action class.

Comment: Can you provide the struts action mapping in question. Also specify whether struts project is present in same container as that of your spring project.