# response.sendRedirect(url) in Spring MVC controller to external host actually redirects to local host

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I ve done some researches but couldn't find any question or answer that could help me,

so my probleme is as below :

I have a controller that redirects to an external link :

```
@controller("person")
publi class PersonController(){

    @RequestMapping(value="redirect",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String redirectToExternalLink(params...){
        String url = "https://externalHost.com/doSomthing";
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
}
```

after going through this method, I find my self face to a 404 error Page not Found, when I check the link I ve been redrected to I find :

*www.mydomainName.com*/**doSomthing**

As you can see, the external domain name is replaced by mine, I ve tried also this :

```
response.setHeader("Location",url);
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

same issue.

is it a configuration that I should do on tomcat ? or there is a way to solve it ?

thanks

Comment: That code won't compile as-is, can you include the actual code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this question, [Redirect to an external URL from controller action in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc).
If you encounter the common problem.

For my case, it was a network configurations issue (URL rewriting).

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

is correct. However, I would double check the url redirected to. I would also run the code in debug mode and check if

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

is executed in the first place.