# How to use Redirect in ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I Want to redirect my url to http://localhost:8080/ClickBuy/product/details to          http://localhost:8080/ClickBuy/home .

I have Define header.jsp and Include it in all my Pages.When I click home link from anywhere else url add /home from current url.So it shows 404 error.

### Controller

```
public ModelAndView allProduct()
{   
ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("pl");
model.addObject("data", pd.getAllProducts());
return model;
}
```

How can I use redirect:/ in ModelAndView return type method???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17961336/3959856

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To Use  redirect:/ in ModelAndView return type method, you are try following

```
ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm");
modelAndView.addObject("modelAttribute" , new ModelAttribute());
return modelAndView;
```

You can also return home page using String returntype if you do not need any Model in home page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String homePage() {
      return "home";
   }
```

Comment: 'ModelAttribute' is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to redirect but using Spring ModelView Object is simple

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirecturl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView methodPost() {
            return new ModelAndView( "redirect:/login.html");

    }
```

Comment: I used above approach, but the redirection to an external URL happens with POST method, can I change it to GET?