# How do you redirect from hostname to FQDN?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, http-redirect

I have a Spring Boot application that is HTTPS enabled and I am using a self-signed certificate. The application can be accessed using just the hostname or the fully qualified hostname (with domain). The application knows the hostname and the domain (values are stored in a property file that the application has access to). I would like to put a redirect in place so that it always goes to the URL with the fully qualified hostname. In other words, accessing https://mymachine:8888 should redirect to https://mymachine.mydomain.com:8888. How can I do do that?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc ?