# How to force the browser to redo the previous call after a redirect?

Tags: java, spring, jwt, redirect

Currently prototyping a new application with Spring boot & Spring security we have put in place working solution for our authentication.

To simplify, on each call we use Spring Security to test if a JWT token exists in the cookies and is valid.

If not, we redirect to another URL where we perform SSO with Kerberos (With a fallback to Basic authentication if SSO is not working) then we redirect back to the original with a new JWT token set in the cookies.

The current solution that we use is to add a "redirect" parameter when redirecting to the authentication URL, as well as the paramters :

```
RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/auth/token?redirect=" + request.getServletPath() + "&" + request.getQueryString());
```

Then in the authentication URL, when the authentication is successful, we redirect back to the original "redirect" URL :

```
CookiesUtils.setCookie(request, response, Constants.JWT_COOKIE_ACCESS, principal.getToken());

RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, request.getParameter("redirect") + "?" + request.getQueryString());
```

This is only working with GET parameters but the original call can be of any type, even a POST with upload data.

So I was wondering: **is it possible to just put something in the redirect to force the browser to redo the previous call?**

Any other solution is welcome of course ! :-)

Comment: To my knowledge and experience from another spring project, redirecting from an ajax request is not possible from the server. Your best bet is to set a status code and let the front-end check and do the redirecting/redo. Or if i didn't understand you can look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I do now, but this only works for GET requests and cannot redirect if the original call was a POST for example.