# How to implement "load balancer" using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, proxy, httprequest

Depends on request body content I need to redirect http requests to `URL_1` or `URL_2`.

I started controller implementation:

```
@RestController
public class RouteController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public HttpServletResponse route(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String body = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
        if(isFirstServer(body)) {
            //send request to URL_1 and get response
        } else {
            //send request to URL_2 and get response
        }
    }
}
```

Request might be `GET` or `POST` ot `PUT` or `PATCH` etc.

Could you help me to write that code?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a somehow similar question a while ago. Plea see [Server side redirect for REST call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479379/server-side-redirect-for-rest-call) for more context.

The best way (to my current understanding) you could achieve this is by manually invoking the desired endpoints from your initial endpoint.

```
@RestController
public class RouteController {

    @Value("${firstUrl}")
    private String firstUrl;

    @Value("${secondUrl}")
    private String secondUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public void route(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String body = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
        if(isFirstServer(body)) {
            restTemplate.exchange(firstUrl,
                                  getHttpMethod(request), 
                                  getHttpEntity(request), 
                                  getResponseClass(request), 
                                  getParams(params));
        } else {
            restTemplate.exchange(secondUrl,
                                  getHttpMethod(request), 
                                  getHttpEntity(request), 
                                  getResponseClass(request), 
                                  getParams(params))
        }
   }
}
```

Example implementation for `getHttpMethod`:

```
public HttpMethod getHttpMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod());
}
```

Similar implementations for `getHttpEntity`, `getResponseClass` and `getParams`. They are used for converting the data from the `HttpServletRequest request` to the types required by the `exchange` method.

There seem to be a lot of better ways of doing this for a Spring MVC app, but I guess that it does not apply to your context.

Another way you could achieve this would be defining your own REST client and adding the routing logic there.

Comment: could you show implementation getHttpMethod getHttpEntity getResponseClass getParams?

Comment: And what is params?

Comment: `params` are any request parameters that are sent along with the original request.

Comment: Could you, please, provide getHttpEntity and getParams method content?

Comment: For the params, please take a look at `getQueryString` on `HttpServletRequest`. For the HTTP entity, it should be based on the `request.getReader()` you already use combined with, for example, Jackson. Both implementations could be simplified if you can add `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` to your endpoints and let Spring do those conversions for you.