# Spring Boot - Issues redirecting to external URL with AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, backend

I am using Spring Boot for the first time to setup a user login system for a REACT web-app. As of now I am trying to redirect the user to another page in my REACT-app after a successful  authentication. I am using a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler to handle the actual redirection.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v*/login/**");
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v*/login/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/v*/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("PRODUCER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin().loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login").successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
```

```
 @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
        return new RedirectLoginSuccessHandler();
    }
```

```
public class RedirectLoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:3000");
    }

}
```

The API runs on port :8080 and the react login form runs on :3000/login, authentication is done by sending a POST-request to localhost:8080/api/v1/login (getting a JWT access token in return), after that is attempted I want the user to get redirected to the homepage at localhost:3000, but the redirect is being ignored unless I use the login form that you get from Spring with the loginForm() method.

I also tried sending a redirect along with the JWT token as a response to the POST-request to api/v1/login, but ran into problems with CORS doing that. What am I doing wrong here? The tutorials i've seen on redirecting after successful authentication refer to html files such as home.html to redirect, and I am assuming they are able to do this by having bundled together the REACT and Spring boot project into one mono-repository.

[Cors issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czC0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this ...

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            // ... endpoints
            .formLogin()
                ... config
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000l", true)
            // ... other configuration       
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried setting the .defaultSuccessUrl to localhost:3000 and true, and that worked using the login form from Spring on localhost:8080, (I get redirected to :3000) but still nothing happening if I use my custom log-in form created in REACT (under the URL localhost:3000/login). Would the ordering in the configure method that you suggested make a difference? To clarify, what I want is the front-end (:3000) and back-end(:8080) to be completely separated, and that when an auth attempt is sent with credentials with a POST from 3000/login to 8080/api/v1/login when successful redirect to :3000/home.

Comment: Maybe this can work https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396175/2599899

Comment: Also this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-react

Comment: Give it a go and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

With `formLogin`, Spring Security basically provides you these steps (simplified):

1. When you call an API need to authenticate the user, if AccessDeniedException happens, a `AuthenticationEntryPoint` will redirect you to `formLogin().loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login")`.
2. After the user fill out the `username` and the `password`, you need to POST them to `formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login123")` (default value if you don't specicify should be "/login").
3. The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, after that, bases on the matcher on `"/login123"` will intercept your POST, and validate your user with `username` and `password`.
4. If they are validated successfully, your `.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())` will be called to do its job.

...

---

Here, because

> authentication is done by sending a POST-request to localhost:8080/api/v1/login (getting a JWT access token in return)

You didn't follow the flow from step 2 (you didn't POST username/password to "/login123"), you couldn't get features supported by Spring Security after that (`this.rememberMeServices.loginSuccess`, `this.successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess`,... for example).

---

**For your case**, after you get JWT from `a POST-request to localhost:8080/api/v1/login`, you could redirect by yourself, you don't need to depend on `.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())`.