# Url redirection from a spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am hitting a controller in spring boot application and from there when i return to browser i want it to redirect to another website or url other than spring boot application templates.

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961336/865448

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in many ways

**Using RedirectView**

```
@RequestMapping("/to-be-redirected")
public RedirectView localRedirect() {
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
    return redirectView;
}
```

**Using ResponseEntity**

```
@RequestMapping("/to-be-redirected")
public ResponseEntity<Object> redirectToExternalUrl() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI yahoo = new URI("http://www.yahoo.com");
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setLocation(yahoo);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
}
```

**Using HttpServletResponse**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void redirectToTwitter(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://twitter.com");
}
```

**Using ModelAndView**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + projectUrl);
}
```