# How to download pdf file and redirect to home page in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Following code just work fine there is no error in it but not work as required..

> problem 1: I want to download pdf file and redirect to home
>   page(url:../).when ever i nevigate to url(../admin/generate_pdf)
>
> problem 2:when ever i uncomment the commented line in Pdfdemo.java it
>   gives me an error 404 page not found.

**Pdfdemo.java**

```
public class Pdfdemos {
    private static String USER_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "lokesh";

        public String generate_pdf() {
            try {
                String file_name="d:\\sanjeet7.pdf";
                Document document= new Document();
                PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file_name));

//              writer.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),
//                          OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING |PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS|
//                          PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY|
//                          PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128, 0);


                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph(" "));document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
                String days_in_week[]= {"monday","tuesday","webnesday","thursday","friday","saturday"};
                int period=8;
                String user="springstudent";
                String pass="springstudent";
                String jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false";
                String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                Connection myconn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,pass);
                PreparedStatement ps=null;
                ResultSet rs=null;
                String query="select * from class_t";
                ps=myconn.prepareStatement(query);
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()) {
                    Paragraph para=new Paragraph("Time table for class"+rs.getString("class")+rs.getString("section"));
                    document.add(para);
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
                    PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(period+1);
                    for(int i=0;i<days_in_week.length;i++) {

                        for(int j=0;j<period+1;j++) {

                            if(j==5) {
                                table.addCell("recess");
                            }else {

                                table.addCell("this is "+j);
                            }


                        }


                    }
                    document.add(table);
                    document.newPage();

                }
                document.close();
                System.out.println("finish");





            return file_name;

            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return null;


        }

}
```

**Generate_pdf_controller.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/generate_pdf")
public class Generate_pdf_Controller {


    @GetMapping("/online")
    public String generating_pdf(Model theModel) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        CustomerServiceImpl pal=new CustomerServiceImpl();
        Pdfdemos pal1=new Pdfdemos();
        String xx=pal1.generate_pdf();
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I am able to redirect but not download and redirect at the sae time..

Comment: You can redirect from a web page with using Java Script after downloading a PDF.

Comment: How can I download it ?..And what about second problem...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get the pdf (download into browser from local file system), this code is sufficient:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/generate_pdf")
public class PdfController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/online", /*this is "nice to have" ->*/ produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody // this is important, as the return type byte[]
    public byte[] generating_pdf() throws IOException {//exception handling...
        System.out.println("hello");//logging
        // re-generate new file if needed (thread-safety!)...
        // ..and dump the content as byte[] response body:
        return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("d:\\sanjeet7.pdf"));
    }
}
```

... if you need "a refresh", you can "rewrite" the file/re-call your service, but still maybe not the "thread-safest" solution.

**Edit:** With no further configuration (port/context root/...), You should reach this at: http://localhost:8080/admin/generate_pdf/online

---

If you want to "operate closer to the bytes" and with `void` return type/no `@ResponseBody` **and** want an additional redirect (to be tested), I think this should still work:

```
@Controller
public class ... {

   @GetMapping(value = ..., produces ...)
   //no request body, void return type, response will be autowired and can be handled
   public void generatePdf(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws ... {
      java.io.OutputStream outStr = response.getOutputStream();
      // dump from "somewhere" into outStr, "finally" close.
      outStr.close();
      //TO BE TESTED:
      response.sendRedirect("/");
   }
}
```

..or even (return a "view name" + operate on outputStream):

```
   @GetMapping(value = ..., produces = "application/pdf")
   //return a "view name" (!), and you can inject (only) the outputstream (without enclosing response) 
   public String generatePdf(java.io.OutputStream outputstream) throws... {          
      // ... do your things on outputstream, IOUtils is good...
      // close the stream(?)
      // ..and
      return "redirect:/"; // to a redirect or a view name.
      // .... (in a "spring way", which could also save you some "context path problems"
   } ...
```

Comment: Thank for solution it really work.please  consider about the second problem when I uncomment the pdf password instructions it show me 404 page not found..

Comment: #second_problem: check/test my edit, @sanjeetpal ...and at the frontend, you might have either some options.

Comment: the 404 might also be a "missing error page" (for another error code/problem)

Comment: response.sendRedirect("/admin"); redirect me to localhost:8080/admin instead of local host:8080/project_name/admin

Comment: ..then, you need additionally (to add to method signature) `HttpServletRequest request`, and use `request.getContextPath()` (=`/project_name`) (or obtain it from "somewhere else")

Comment: Adding project_name in request.getContextpath()(=/project_name) doesn't make it deployment friendly everyone I have to change on deploying on different platform....Sorry for irritating you ...I am just asking for community help..

Comment: nono, `request.getContextPath()` is environment safe/works everywhere/comes from browser (plz dont nail me to load balancing&proxy cases)...but still *reconsider* to complete this request with a redirect. (you deliver a "redirect code", but content ... this is not consistent with the purpose of redirect) ..maybe a "new tab" is good enough ...with all browsers

Comment: the use of `"Content-Disposition"`(filename, size, ... see ilia's reply) header might also have some effects on some browsers (IE!?)!

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version of creating and downloading a PDF:

```
@Service
public class PdfService {

    public InputStream createPdf() throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);

        writer.setEncryption("user_password".getBytes(), "owner_password".getBytes(),
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS |
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY |
                    PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128, 0);

        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph("My example PDF document"));
        // some logic here

        document.close();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/generate_pdf")
public class PdfController {

    @Autowired
    private PdfService pdfService;

    @GetMapping("/online")
    public void generatePdf(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"mydocument.pdf\"");

        InputStream pdf = pdfService.createPdf();
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(pdf, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

What about redirecting, as I said in comments, you can do it with using JS at the frontend (after calling the `/admin/generate_pdf/online` url). You can't download file and make refresh/redirect at the same time.