# How to Call a WebController From a RestController And Get A Rendered Template in Response in String In Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, viewrendering

I have invoice-service written in java (Spring Framework) where there are two controllers-

1. InvoicePageController - Annotated with @Controller annotation and a handler generateInvoice inside it which returns a view 'invoice' a html template in the service
2. InvoiceController - Annotated with @RestController annotation and a handler getInvoiceUrl which is supposed to return url of an invoice uploaded to s3

The InvoiceController will get some data in the Request and that data I am passing to InvoicePageController by doing a Rest Call to to same service InvoicePageController class and getting the rendered view in response and stored in a string variable

Now the string which I got in response, I am uploading to S3 and getting it's URL and sending it in the response

Question - I am doing a network call to get the rendered invoice template , If I do a direct call to the method of InvoicePageController then instead of a rendered view I will get the simple 'invoice' string in reponse, So I wanted to know is there a way to get the rendered view with doing the network call

Below is the classes

InvoicePageController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/invoice-page")
public class InvoicePageController {

  @PostMapping
  public String getInvoicePage(@RequestBody InvoiceRequest request, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("labDetails", request.getLabDetails());
    model.addAttribute("order", request.getOrder());
    model.addAttribute("orderItems", request.getOrderItems());
    return "invoice";
  }
}
```

InvoiceController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/invoice")
public class InvoiceController {
  
  @Autowired RestHelper restHelper;
  @Autowired S3Service s3Service;

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<String> getInvoiceUrl(@RequestBody InvoiceRequest request) {
    // Call to a helper method with the payload to get the rendered invoice in the string variable
    String invoicePage = restHelper.getInvoicePage(request);
    String invoiceUrl = s3Service.uploadToS3AndGetUrl(invoicePage);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(invoiceUrl, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Note -

1. I am using thymeleaf for view rendering
2. Upon doing the network call the rendered view comes as string properly

Query - Is there a way to get the rendered view directly instead of doing a network call

Comment: I don't understand "Is there a way to get the rendered view directly instead of doing a network call". Do you mean that you want the browser to redirect to that S3 URL automatically? Or do you want to show the contents of that S3 URL somehow on your own Thymeleaf page?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I want to get the S3 URL from the api response and the content of that S3 object should be the rendered html page

Comment: So you want the browser to redirect to the S3 URL. In that case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc should help.