# Servlet forward request without change URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

Is there any way to redirect to specific URL in rest controller in spring boot using by servlet and not change the URL?
for example I'm gonna redirect user to google site but URL and context is accessible!

```
@RequestMapping("/redirecting")
public RedirectView localRedirect() {
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setUrl("http://google.com");
    return redirectView;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @iswailyildiz I've seen that but it show the context. I want to hide the URL and context and just view the result web page.

Comment: Spring doesn't currently offer an easy way to do this and I guess it won't. You can manually read and return the google html source code.

Comment: BTW thank you dear for your informations.

Comment: You really need to do this in java app? How about nginx proxy_pass?

Comment: nginx not work for my solution