# Redirect to external URL from request mapping method in spring

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is the request mapping method:

```
@GetMapping("/redirect")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect() {

        String url = "http://yahoo.com";

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .location(URI.create(url))
                .build();
    }
```

When I hit the URL http://somehost:8080/redirect in the browser I see that it takes me to yahoo.com, but when the /redirect is called from the UI(reactjs) the 302 Found httpstatus value is returned in the browser console but the page on the browser is blank. I was expecting to see the yahoo.com page. Seems it is not redirecting.

I referred this link: [Redirect to an external URL from controller action in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc)

reactjs code:

```
yield globalAxios.get(http://somehost:8080/redirect)
```

Below image when the http://somehost:8080/redirect gets called from the UI
[image]

Below image is when we the /redirect redirects to the link: yahoo.com

[image]

Is it because of the 405 method not allowed error as seen in the above image

Comment: As it's working as expected with a direct call, I would suggest to change/add the tags of your question to include reactjs and to add the section of the reactjs code in your question.

Comment: You are using a JS framework to do requests and as such the browser doesn't handle the redirect the JS framework is. So you need to add code to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone run into something like this in the future.

I end up using this code getting rid of 405 method not allowed while I am doing PUT-REDIRECT-GET pattern.

Notice it is **@Controller** and not **@RestContorller**. Otherwise it won't work.

If this is to be implemented in an existing rest controller you may want to add @ResponseBody over the other methods but not on these.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/redirect")
public class RedirectController {

@PutMapping()
public String redirect() {
    return "redirect:/redirect";
}

@GetMapping()
public String redirectPost() {
    return "redirect:https://www.google.com";
}
```

}